# Android Studio SQLite string comparison

Tags: string, sqlite, android-studio

I want to compare the date from a calendarView (year-month-day) to a date stored in a database. The problem is that, while they look the same, the query does not return anything from the db.

This is the date i insert into it:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String mDay = Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    String mMon = Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
    String mYear = Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    String formattedDate = mYear + "-" + mMon + "-" + mDay;
    contentValues.put(COL1, item);
    contentValues.put(COL2, time);
    contentValues.put(COL3, formattedDate);
```

It looks like this : 2019-12-5 (from log)

And this is the date i'm getting from the calendarView:

```
    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
                    String dom = Integer.toString(dayOfMonth);
                    String mo = Integer.toString(month + 1);
                    String ye = Integer.toString(year);
                    String date = ye + "-" + mo + "-" + dom;
                    Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData(date);
```

It also looks like this: 2019-12-5 (taken from log)

And here is where i query the table:

```
    public Cursor getData(String date){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL3 + "=" + date;
            Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
            return data;
}
```

The query doesn't return anything.

When i try to query only the day of month it works.

Comment: What happens if you print out the query? I'd guess it looked like `... = 2019-12-5`. And `2019-12-5` is just an arithmetic expression evaluating to 2002.

Comment: @sticky bit  It looks like this : `D/QUERY: SELECT * FROM history_table WHERE PERIOD=2019-12-5`

Comment: I've also tried with "/" instead of "-" and it's the same.

Comment: Yeah, as that would evaluate to 33.65...

Comment: Nevermind. I somehow forgot "/" is an operator aswell. I tried it with nothing in-between and it worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Adrian If you've not already adopted [MikeT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59204651/2096401), note that "nothing in between" is liable to incorrectly match 2019-11-1 and 2019-1-11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you aren't enclosing the date in single quotes, it is therefore taken as an arithmetic expression resulting in 2019 - 12 - 05 = 2002.

Instead of :-

```
public Cursor getData(String date){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL3 + "=" + date;
            Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
            return data;
}
```

Use either :-

```
public Cursor getData(String date){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL3 + "=?";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,new String[]{date});
    return data;
}
```

- This properly escapes/encloses the date in single quotes) and in doing so protects against SQLInjection.

or instead use :-

```
public Cursor getData(String date){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,COL3+"=?,new String[]{date},null,null,null);
}
```

- This uses the [**query**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) convenience method (this being the typically recommended solution). This also properly encloses strings in quotes and protects against SQL Injection as well as generating the SQL on your behalf and is therefore less prone to mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps as I've got a filter system using a SQL database and then checking that data by a input from the user.

First thing to note is in my database I store the date as a string.

When I add the date I do it like so:

`date = calendar.getTime().toString();`

Then I need to get the time for the user this is done via:

```
private Calendar Start_filter_String;
private Calendar Stop_filter_String;
private Calendar database_cal;
```

```
String parse_string_start;
String parse_string_stop;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

```
parse_string_start = "Mon"+ " "
                        +Month_Spinner_value+" "
                        +Day_Spinner_value  +" "
                        +Hour_Spinner_value +":"
                        +Minute_Spinner_value+":"
                        +"00"+" "+"GMT"+" "
                        +Year_Spinner_value;
                    Start_filter_String.setTime(sdf.parse(parse_string_start));
```

Then this code below check the time you pass in. Note my SQL database is done via a cursor to data. Also my time string is stored in column 8.

```
try {
                        database_cal.setTime(sdf.parse(data.getString(8)));
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(Start_filter_String.compareTo(database_cal) == 1)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Filter: Data is not after start time");
                    }
                    if(Stop_filter_String.compareTo(database_cal) == 1)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Filter: Data is not before stop time");
                    }
                    if(Start_filter_String.compareTo(database_cal) == -1)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Filter: Data is after start time");
                    }
                    if(Stop_filter_String.compareTo(database_cal) == -1)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Filter: Data is before stop time");
                    }
```

Hope this helps